# WPF MVVM dynamic observable collection binding to data grid

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm

I have a unique problem in my wpf mvvm application.
I have a `GridContol`(View) in my application for which I have to bind a observable collections. I have different ObservableCollections for different clients. Depending on the client i have to load data on gridcontrol(View). so with one binding on gridControl(View) how can i acheive this.

```
<dxg:GridControl 
ItemsSource="{Binding CommonBindingType??????}">   
</dxg:GridControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a property on your view model that is a reference to the right collection.

```
<dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionSource}" />
```

Of course, fill my source with appropiate INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public class YourViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<blah> Source1 { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<blah> Source2 { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<blah> CollectionSource { get; set; }
    public YourViewModel()
    {
        CollectionSource = Source1;
    }
    public void ChangeToSource2()
    {
        CollectionSource = Source2;
    }
}
```

If your collections are of different generic types, then CollectionSource should be something a bit more generic, like

```
public IEnumerable<object> CollectionSource { get; set; }
```

Comment: But what about the different generic types and their different Properties? Type blah1 has Prename whereas blah2 has Price and Amount.

Comment: I don't think it matters, WPF binds and uses the objects at runtime, it doesn't do any checks during compile time. Actually, just make CollectionSource an object, no need for IEnumerable<object>. WPF will figure out the rest.

Comment: Thanks Joel Lucsy for awesome answer :):)  but i m getting another problem. when i load data to grid few objects(not variables) also populating as columns that i dont. please help me with this

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to crate dynamic viewmodels.But most of them uses .NET 4.0 dynamic type or ExpandoObject.

You need to crate generic viewmodels which can very at runtime and bind this generic viewmodel with the controls in view.

You can follow Following approaches/examples:

1)
http://www.shujaat.net/2012/09/dynamicobject-wpf-binding.html

2)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/613610/Dynamic-View-Model

Comment: I successfully achieved this by extending DynamicObject with INotifyPropertyChanged and IDictionary.  However INotifyDataErrorInfo is not picking up the validation errors from the individual items in the dictionary, so I'm looking for alternate solutions.